# How the PowerShell Cmdlets that have a ComputerName parameter authenticate to remote computers?

Tags: powershell, remoting, powershell-remoting

Some PowerShell Cmdlets have a `ComputerName` parameter and I can use them to get information from remote computers. Like `Get-Process`, `Get-Service` etc. However, they don't have a `Credential` parameter, which in turn makes the command fail in some circumstances. Like the following example.

```
PS C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming> Get-Service *sql* -ComputerName mylab.testing.com
Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'mylab.testing.com'. This operation might require other privileges.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Service *sql* -ComputerName mylab.testing.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

PS C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming> Get-Error
******************************
Errors: 104
******************************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
----------------------------------------------
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: ScriptHalted
----------------------------------------------
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
----------------------------------------------
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
----------------------------------------------
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:18 char:21
+                     write-host $err.Exception.ToString()
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

----------------------------------------------
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
At line:9 char:17
+         foreach($err in $Error)
+                 ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException

ScriptHalted
At line:22 char:9
+         throw
+         ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptHalted

PS C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming> help Get-Service -full
```

Note I used a custom function Get-Error and its code is listed below.

```
function Get-Error
{
    $errorsReported = $False
    if($Error.Count -ne 0)
    {
        write-host "******************************"
        write-host "Errors:", $Error.Count
        write-host "******************************"
        foreach($err in $Error)
        {
            $errorsReported  = $True
            if( $err.Exception.InnerException -ne $null)
            {
                    write-host $err.Exception.InnerException.ToString()
            }
            else
            {
                    write-host $err.Exception.ToString()
            }

            write-host "----------------------------------------------"
        }
        throw
    }

}
```

I want to know whether my understanding is correct? Does that simply means it's impossible to authenticate to remote servers when using those commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be running your PowerShell session with an account that has admin rights on the remote computer as capsch says. If the remote computer has remoting enabled, you could run the Get-Service command using Invoke-Command and remoting, which does support alternate credentials. Another alternative is to use WMI and query services that way which also supports alternate credentials.

Answer (score 0):

UAC aside you by default have to be an admin of member to administer remotely

Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer